# Writing STDIN to a file using filehandle in perl

Tags: perl, stdin, filehandle

I have just started learning perl and I was going through filehandle.

1. I want to write my STDIN to a file. How do I do it using filehandle ?
2. Also is it possible to do the same, without using FH ?

I tried the below, but never worked:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file = 'File.txt';

open ($fh, '>', $file) or die "Error :$!";

print "Enter blank line to end\n";

while (<STDIN>) {

    last if /^$/;
    print "FH: $fh \n";
    print "dollar: $_ \n";
}

close $fh;*
```

The below works, but I don't understand why.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(my $fh, '>', 'report.txt');

foreach my $line ( <STDIN> ) {

    chomp( $line );

    print $fh "$line\n";
}

close $fh;


print "done\n";
```

Comment: In the second case, you print to $fh, but in the first you don't.

Comment: Please take the time to ensure that the code in your question is well-formatted. Someone else has fixed it for you this time, but it's rude to expect someone else to do it for you.

Comment: It's unfair to treat this site as a source of free private programming tutorials. We subscribe primarily to help our peers with seemingly intractable problems, and writing to a file isn't difficult. [The *information* page for the **Perl** tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info) has many excellent resources, and it is best if you find them and learn for yourself. You will need to study your subject anyway, and turning over an answer that you were given here will not help you to learn. Please rethink your approach to your course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have opened the filehandle `$fh` for writing to your file. Your second example prints data to this filehandle, so it works:

```
print $fh "$line\n";
```

But your first example doesn't print to `$fh`, so the output goes to `STDOUT`.

```
print "FH: $fh \n";
print "dollar: $_ \n";
```

In order for your first example to work, you need to print to the correct filehandle.

```
print $fh "FH: $fh \n";
print $fh "dollar: $_ \n";
```